# C Declare the struct before definition

Tags: c, struct

The following is the source code that is problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Foo
{
    int a;
    Bar b;
} Foo;

typedef struct Bar
{
    int a;
    int b;
} Bar;

int main(void)
{
    Foo f;
    f.a = 1;
    f.b.a = 2;
    f.b.b = 3;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", f.a, f.b.a, f.b.b);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to declare the `Bar` struct in the `Foo` struct that keep order of the struct declarations (`Foo` struct is first). But I can't, it occurs some errors(One is `error: unknown type name 'Bar'`) in the compile time.

How to do it?

Comment: Declare Foo after Bar.

Comment: You can't do it. You have to put the declaration of `Bar` before you declare any objects with that type.

Comment: Put your typedef's inside a headerfile.

Comment: If you want `Bar b` as a member, the answer is *you can't*. If you want an *indirect* `Bar *pb`, then you can with appropriate *forward* declaring.

Comment: Oh! Thanks to everyone who submitted answers.

Comment: use a template ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The compiler needs to be able to determine the size of `Foo`. If `Bar` is unknown at the time `Foo` is defined the compiler can not determine the size of `Foo`. The only way around this is using a pointer since all pointers have the same size.

You can use a forward declaration of the structure and then reference it as a pointer.
This means that `Foo` can never automatically allocate the memory for `Bar`. As a consequence the memory has to be allocated separately.

If you can avoid this do not do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Bar Bar;
typedef struct Foo Foo;

struct Foo
{
    int a;
    Bar * b;
};

struct Bar
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

void dynamic(void)
{
    Foo f;

    f.a = 1;
    f.b = (Bar*)malloc(sizeof(Bar));
    f.b->a = 2;
    f.b->b = 3;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", f.a, f.b->a, f.b->b);

    free(f.b);
}

void automatic(void)
{
    Foo f;
    Bar b;

    f.a = 1;
    f.b = &b;
    f.b->a = 2;
    f.b->b = 3;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", f.a, f.b->a, f.b->b);
}

int main(void)
{
    dynamic();
    automatic();
}
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to make things symmetric: `typedef struct Bar Bar; typedef struct Foo Foo; struct Bar { … }; struct Foo { … };`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - feel free :) Everything that makes it prettier is welcome.

Comment: I felt free!  Free at last!  Happy day...OK; maybe not, but I did edit it.

Answer (score 1):

The Bar struct declaration has to precede the Foo struct declaration - in case you do not want to use pointers and allocate memory. In C, if you have another struct as a member in a struct, the other struct has to be declared before so as the compiler can see it.

Answer (score -2):

Tada!

```
#define Bar struct { int a; int b; }

typedef struct Foo
{
    int a;
    Bar b;
} Foo;

#undef Bar

typedef struct Bar
{
    int a;
    int b;
} Bar;

int main(void)
{
    Foo f;
    f.a = 1;
    f.b.a = 2;
    f.b.b = 3;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", f.a, f.b.a, f.b.b);

    return 0;
}
```

(please don't do this)

Comment: Not my down-vote, but there are sufficiently many problems with this that you should delete it.  I know you say "Don't do it", but...

Comment: whatever man, programmers with a sense of humor will appreciate it

Comment: sorry that sounded harsh, should be reworded to "Hey, programmers need to have some stimulus for their unusual sense of humor now and then."